# How to make a class thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

How to make the following Java class thread safe?

```java
class Test {

    int size;
    int index;
    String[] a;


    Test() {
        a = new String[10];
        size = 10;
    }


    Test(int b) {
        a = new String[b];
        size = b;
    }


    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }


    public void addElement(String s) {
        if (a.length < size) {
            a[index] = s;
            index++;
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }


    public String getElement(int i) {
        if (i < index) {
            return a[i - 1];
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

1. Is it enough to make the `String[] a;` variable `volatile`?
2. Or do i need to use the `synchronized` keyword?

My assumption is that `synchronized` is not needed for the methods `getSize()` and `getElement()`. Is that correct?

Comment: the best way to create thread save objects is to define them immutable!!

Comment: All instance variables must be `private`.

Comment: 1. No. 2. Yes.: You have two options: Either you synchronize the access on the fields correctly *or* you make `Test` an immutable class. I'm sure someone will post an answer soon with more details.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

1. Volatile is a mechanisms for data integrity. Basically you are telling the compiler that a variable is likely to change by code executing in another thread, so that it should always get it from memory and not from the cache.
2. `synchronized` is the way to go in you case. For a synchronized array what you need to protect are the writes because they will modify the contents of the array. Additionally, as pointed out in the comments, adding the `synchronized` keyword to the `getElement` method will guarantee that it will get executed after any concurrent `addElement` call so it will always use the most recent elements in the array. The official docs on [Synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) has more details.

   ```
    class Test {

      private final int size;
      private final String[] a;
      private int index;

      Test() {
        this(10);
      }

      Test(int b) {
        this.a = new String[b];
        this.size = b;
        this.index = 0;
      }

      public int getSize() {
        return size;
      }

      public synchronized void addElement(String s) {
        if (a.length < size) {
          a[index] = s;
          index++;
        } else {
          throw IndexOutOfBoundsException("Can't hold more elements");
        }
      }

      public synchronized String getElement(int i) {
        if (i < index) {
          return a[i - 1];
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: + make the fields (size, index, a) private to make shure they can only be changed in synchronized context.

Comment: @VinZ added complete code example with your suggestions

Comment: `index` cannot be final.

Comment: Also,  `getElement` has to be synchronized  for thread safety. `this.index = 0;` is useless.

Comment: if you don't initialise the *index* then you would get a null pointer exception when you call `a[index]`. Two threads can safely call `getElement` so no need for synchronisation since *getElement* does not modify the state of the Test instance.

Comment: `getElement` does need to be synchronized in the case of concurrent access to `addElement`.